# Finding if 2 squares are sharing a side

Tags: c++, math, geometry

Im wondering how could i find if 2 square share a same side.

i have 2 information:
position and size

position is the left up corner of the square

```
+---+---+   
|   s   |   
|   s   |   
+---+---+
```

here s is the shared side of both square

Comment: 1) calculate the four corners 2) ??? 3) profit.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does it mean to share a side? Must it be complete side? What about only a partial side share? What about only sharing a corner?

Comment: @tenfour haven't tried anything, I've been thinking about some vector algebra in order to know if its complete side or not, but I'm stuck here at knowing if there is at least a part of the side in common

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you lack "orientation" as a datum, we will assume that they are orthogonal to the axes. At this point it becomes a matter of checking if either of the horizontal or vertical edges are collinear (which is trivial since you don't need to worry about orientation), and then seeing if either corner falls within the other square's side or vice versa.

Comment: i may have find a solution thx to you. if i substitute square coordinate. having square 1: ((x1,y1), size1) and square 2:((x2,y2), size2) and find that x2-x1 or y2-y1 equals size1 it may mean that they are sharing the same side.